Skew-symmetric matrix least-square problem.
Is there a simple solution to the following problem:
Given $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$,
$$
\min_{A\in  M^n(\mathbb{R})} \left\| \left(\frac{A-A^t}{2}\right)x - y\right\|^2
$$
Or equivalently $\min ||Ax-y||^2$ where A is skew-symmetric.
I know that in dimensions 2 and 3, the solution involves the cross-product, but I'm looking for a simple solution for general dimensions.
The problem is of course under-constrained, maybe the matrix with smaller norm frobenus norm would be the more natural one?
Thank you !

Here is some discussion of the case where $A$ is symmetric. It may lead to some fruitful ideas https://mathoverflow.net/questions/339878/symmetric-linear-least-squares-solution

See as well https://mathoverflow.net/q/221584/88984

Since symmetric matrices are orthogonal to skew-symmetric matrices (with respect to Frobenius inner product) and the symmetric part of $A$ does not contribute to the objective function, all global minimisers in the OP with the smallest Frobenius norms must be skew-symmetric. So, let us assume that $A$ is skew-symmetric below.
If $x=0$, clearly every skew-symmetric matrix $A$ is a global minimiser and the one with the smallest norm is $A=0$.
Now suppose that $x\ne0$. Since $A$ is skew-symmetric, $Ax$ lies inside $\{x\}^\perp$. As the component of $y$ in $\{x\}^\perp$ is $v=y-\frac{y^Tx}{x^Tx}x$, we have $\|Ax-y\|^2=\|Ax-v\|^2+\|y-v\|^2$. Hence $A$ is a global minimiser whenever $Ax=v$. In particular,
$$
A_0=\frac{1}{x^Tx}(vx^T-xv^T)
$$
is a global minimiser. This solution also has the smallest Frobenius norm among all global minimisers. This is evident when $v=0$ (because $A_0=0$). When $v\ne0$, normalise $x$ and $v$ to two mutually orthogonal unit vectors $x'$ and $v'$. Then $A_0v'=-\frac{\|v\|}{\|x\|}x'$. Complete $\{x',v'\}$ to an orthonormal basis $\{x',v',u_3,u_4,\ldots,u_n\}$ of $\mathbb R^n$. For any skew-symmetric solution to $Ax=v$, we have
$$
\|Av'\|
=\frac{\|Av\|}{\|v\|}
\ge\frac{|\langle Av, x'\rangle|}{\|v\|}
=\frac{|\langle v, A^Tx'\rangle|}{\|v\|}
=\frac{|\langle v, Ax'\rangle|}{\|v\|}
=\frac{\|v\|}{\|x\|}
=\|A_0v'\|.
$$
It follows that
\begin{align*}
\|A\|_F^2
&=\|Ax'\|^2+\|Av'\|^2+\|Au_3\|^2+\cdots+\|Au_n\|^2\\
&\ge\|Ax'\|^2+\|Av'\|^2\\
&\ge\|Ax'\|^2+\|A_0v'\|^2\\
&=\|A_0x'\|^2+\|A_0v'\|^2\\
&=\|A_0x'\|^2+\|A_0v'\|^2+\|A_0u_3\|^2+\cdots+\|A_0u_n\|^2\\
&=\|A_0\|_F^2.
\end{align*}

Indeed ! Thank you very much !
